# Is the advice I find to use \colon for punctuation and : for set notation outdated

Tags: luatex, punctuation

I am working on a novel that include a fair amount of religious discussion, including citing bible verses.

The advice I find on various sites on the internet is to use \colon for punctuation and reserve the use of : for set notation in mathematics - of which there is none in my novel. :-)

In practice, I find \colon does nothing in text - but : works just fine.

For example,

```
He broke the silence, ``Joshua 23:8 in the KJV says `This day you shall
cleave unto the LORD your God' --- \emph{Adonai Elohehem}.''
```

precisely what I want - it is typeset as "Joshua 23:8". But

```
He broke the silence, ``Joshua 23\colon 8 in the KJV says `This day you shall
cleave unto the LORD your God' --- \emph{Adonai Elohehem}.''
```

is typeset as "Joshua 23 8".

Is the advice about using \colon outdated?

I am using LuaLatex if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

The advice you found is about colons in math formulas. In text the colon is input just with `:`.

For the case at hand, Knuth would suggest `Joshua~23\thinspace:\thinspace 8`, but it's a stylistic preference (The TeXbook, page 311).

In case you want to follow Knuth's advice, it's better to define a `\bcolon` command, say

```
\newcommand{\bcolon}{\unskip\thinspace:\thinspace}
```

and type

```
Joshua~23\bcolon 8
```

or even

```
Joshua~23 \bcolon 8
```

so you can easily change the style by modifying the definition. The `\unskip` instruction guarantees that if you inadvertently type a space before `\bcolon` it will be eaten up.

The tie between the book name and the chapter number is recommended so as not to have a line break at the spot. Besides, it doesn't produce an end-of-sentence period in case the book name is abbreviated.

Comment: I was able to find support for Knuth's suggestion in a copy of the 7th ed. of the Chicago Manual of Style (1920), which I found online. It says "Put a centered (9-unit) colon between chapter and verse in Scripture passages, between hours and minutes in time indications, and between volume and page reference when such style is used." Elsewhere is says that there are 18 units in a quad when discussing the Monotype machine. I assume the "9-unit" refers to the total width of the colon and the space on either side, but don't know for certain.

Comment: Thanks very much!